# Coordinator layout + viewpager weird jittering effect

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, androiddesignsupport, android-nestedscrollview

Basic coordinator layout causing jittering effect when flinging (as shown in the video)

This effect, apparently only happens on Huawei (Or low end devices in general). Same code working fine on Samsung s7 edge ( and generally high end devices like mine OP6)

I tried altering the scroll flags, but in vain. I also tried to go with the  custom behavior route, however, there is no direction for me there. Like I haven't clearly identified the issue (or the bug in the design support library) to work around it with some custom behavior. I have reached some sort of a dead end about this.

**Here is the effect in motion:**

[image]

**Edit: Adding xml code**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
android:focusable="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbarView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/toolbar_color"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:contentScrim="@color/transparent"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="top"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:statusBarScrim="@color/transparent"
        app:titleEnabled="false">


        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewRecipeName"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_regular"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color_18"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewRating"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:text="Greek salad filled filo cupsGreek salad filled filo cups" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewRecipeCuisines"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_regular"
                android:maxLines="4"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color_19"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/textViewRecipeName"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textViewRecipeName"
                tools:text="Salads - Appetizers" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewRating"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
                android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_medium"
                android:letterSpacing="-0.02"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color_18"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textViewRecipeName"
                tools:text="5.0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewRatingLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_regular"
                android:text="@string/home_text_rating"
                android:textColor="@color/text_grey"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/textViewRating"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/textViewRating"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textViewRating" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewForRecipe"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="183dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textViewRecipeCuisines" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewPlayVideo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageViewForRecipe"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageViewForRecipe"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageViewForRecipe"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageViewForRecipe"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_play_video" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewPrepTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_prep_time"
                android:drawablePadding="6dp"
                android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_regular"
                android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="12sp"
                android:textColor="@color/recipeDetailsColor"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageViewForRecipe"
                tools:text="30 min" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider1"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:background="@color/dividerGreyColor"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/textViewPrepTime"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textViewPrepTime"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textViewPrepTime" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewCookTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_cook_time"
                android:drawablePadding="6dp"
                android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_regular"
                android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="12sp"
                android:textColor="@color/recipeDetailsColor"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/divider1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/divider1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageViewForRecipe"
                tools:text="10 min" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider2"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:background="@color/dividerGreyColor"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/textViewPrepTime"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textViewCookTime"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textViewPrepTime" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewCapacity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_serving"
                android:drawablePadding="6dp"
                android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_regular"
                android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="12sp"
                android:textColor="@color/recipeDetailsColor"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/divider2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/divider2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageViewForRecipe"
                tools:text="12 pcs" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewAboutThisRecipeLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
                android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_medium"
                android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="10sp"
                android:text="@string/about_this_recipe"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color_18"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/textViewRecipeName"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textViewCapacity" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewAboutRecipeValue"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_regular"
                android:letterSpacing="0.02"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="10sp"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color_19"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/textViewRatingLabel"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/textViewRecipeName"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textViewAboutThisRecipeLabel"
                tools:text="A tosty and filling russian main course, rich in flavor. this plate was invented by rubio safona back in the 1950s after he was in france during WWII" />


        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_alwadi"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewFavorite"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_heart"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewShare"
                    android:layout_width="18dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_share"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageViewFavorite"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewNoMenuItems"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/group_13"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:text="No Items found!"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible" />


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayoutViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/tabLayoutTextAppearance"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/tab_layout_normal_text_color" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPagerIngredientsPrep"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/linearLayoutButtons"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutButtons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/buttonToggleFavorite"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/add_to_favorites"
                android:textAppearance="@style/ButtonTextAppearance" />

            <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/buttonRateThisRecipe"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:text="@string/rate_this_recipe_text"
                android:textAppearance="@style/ButtonTextAppearance" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: could you add please android version where you are getting the issue? Are you using VideoView or are you using exo player? this wired behaviour can be related to SurfaceView.

Comment: Android 5.0, No am not using VideoView nor am using exo player, this is just an icon indicating that there exist a video for this item. clicking on this play icon will navigate to another screen with the video playing. @AnisBENNSIR

Comment: could you please post the code for your layout? why you are using CoordinatorLayout? is there any scrolling interaction on your screen? Is the size of ImageView for the video fixed?

Comment: @AnisBENNSIR I have added the xml layout code. I am using CoordinatorLayout to get the effect of pinning the tablayout and toolbar layout when they reach the top.

Comment: Check my answer here, it fixes your exact problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57441485/3307397

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind this is because `AppBarLayout` does not stop fling when we start fling on any other view of `CoordinatorLayout`. Solution is quite simple: whenever any child view of `CoordinatorLayout` starts fling, we need to stop the fling of `AppBarLayout` (code below is for androidx)

```
class CustomAppBarBehavior : AppBarLayout.Behavior() {

    private var overScroller: OverScroller? = null

    override fun onNestedPreFling(coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout,
                                  child: AppBarLayout,
                                  target: View,
                                  velocityX: Float,
                                  velocityY: Float): Boolean {
        stopAppBarLayoutFling()
        return super.onNestedPreFling(coordinatorLayout, child, target, velocityX, velocityY)
    }

    private fun stopAppBarLayoutFling() {
        if (overScroller == null) {
            val scrollerField = javaClass.superclass.superclass.superclass.getDeclaredField("scroller")
            scrollerField.isAccessible = true
            overScroller = scrollerField.get(this) as? OverScroller
        }
        overScroller?.forceFinished(true)
    }
}
```

In support version 27, finding the scroller via reflection is a bit different:

```
val scrollerField = javaClass.superclass.superclass.getDeclaredField("mScroller")
```